# How to read selected txt file on listview?

Tags: c#

[image]

I would like to read selected text file on listview. Then when click read button, shows read line on text box.

For example, when I select ABC.txt file, then click read button, text box shows read line of ABC.txt.
if select DEF.txt and click read button, text box shows read line of DEF.txt.

How to code selected file's path for streamreader?

```
private void btnrd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string abc = "";
  StreamReader tx = new StreamReader(@"C:\folder\DEF.txt");
  {
    abc = tx.ReadLine();
    textBox2.Text = abc;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide fuller code. In the code you show, there is no ListView even mentioned.

Comment: Is your screenshot a TreeView on the left and a ListView on the right (trying to emulate File Explorer)?  If it is, then you can get the path from the SelectNode.FullPath property of the TreeView and do a little string manipulation to properly format it as a Filepath.  But the easiest thing to is store the filepath as a tag in in the ListViewItems, since you've got it when you select the TreeNode (that's the only way you got the list of files to populate the ListView).  Then just use the tag for your Filepath property in your StreamReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the files re in the same path then you can do the following.

```
string temp=lstView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
private void btnrd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\folder\"+temp+".txt")
}
```

If the files are in different folders then add the path value as the Tag property to the ListViewItem and then

```
string temp=lstView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString();
private void btnrd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(temp)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mean like this?

button1 set > temp="ABC"

button2 set > temp="DEF"

And then :

```
string temp="";
 private void btnrd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string abc = "";
        StreamReader tx = new StreamReader(@"C:\folder\"+temp+".txt");
        {
            abc = tx.ReadLine();
            textBox2.Text = abc;
        }
    }
```